# Error con mi form en php

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php5

primero de todo os presento mi problema, estoy filtrando mi base de datos por la url es decir **<a href='calificaciones3.php?materia=" . $resultado['materia'] . "'>**, y con eso lo que consigo es mostrar una tabla filtrada de las calificaciones de cada alumno en esa materia, lo que yo quiero es por cada fila, en el input de type submit de la tabla, que se abra un div, eso lo he hecho así:

```
<script>
        function abrir(){
        document.getElementById("pitola").style="display:block"
        }
        function cerrar(){
            document.getElementById("pitola").style="display:none"
        }          
        function validar() {
            var nota = document.getElementById("nota").value;
            var actitud = document.getElementById("actitud").value;
            var comentario = document.getElementById("comentario").value;
            
            if (nota == "") {
                document.getElementById("errorNota").style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("errorNota").style.display = "none";
            }
                
            if (actitud == "") {
                document.getElementById("errorActitud").style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
    
            else {
                    document.getElementById("errorActitud").style.display = "none";
            }

            if (comentario == "") {
                document.getElementById("errorComentario").style.display = "block";
                return false;
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("errorComentario").style.display = "none";
            }
            return true;
        }
        if ( window.history.replaceState ) {
            window.history.replaceState( null, null, window.location.href );
        }
    </script>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, todo funciona, para que en ese div me muestren los campos de la tabla en un echo por ejemplo, he tenido que meter el div que abro con mi form, dentro del bucle while, asi:

```
<form method="post">
                    <select name="evaluacion" id="evaluacion" style="min-width: 25%;" required>
                        <option value="EVALUACIÓN" hidden >---</option>
                        <option value="primer_ev">Primera EV</option>
                        <option value="segunda_ev">Segunda EV</option>
                        <option value="tercer_ev">Tercera EV</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="submit" value="Mostrar" name="mostrar" class="btn btn--primary">
                </form>
                <?php
                    if (isset($_POST['mostrar'])) {
                        $evaluacion = $_POST['evaluacion'];

                        // Obtener el id del profesor a partir del correo de inicio de sesión
                        session_start();
                        $correo = $_SESSION['correo'];
                        $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "rootroot", "educados") or die("No se puede conectar con el servidor");
                        $instruccion = "SELECT id_usuario FROM profesor WHERE correo = '$correo'";
                        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $instruccion) or die("Fallo en la consulta");
                        $id_profesor = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)['id_usuario'];

                        // Obtener la materia seleccionada
                        if (isset($_GET['materia'])) {
                            $materia = urldecode($_GET['materia']);
                        } else {
                            print("Debe seleccionar una materia.");
                            exit();
                        }

                        // Obtener las calificaciones filtradas por materia y evaluación
                        $instruccion2 = "SELECT * FROM calificaciones, alumno WHERE id_alumno=id_usuario AND materia = '$materia'";
                        if ($evaluacion == "primer_ev") {
                            $instruccion2 .= " AND primer_ev IS NOT NULL";
                        } elseif ($evaluacion == "segunda_ev") {
                            $instruccion2 .= " AND segunda_ev IS NOT NULL";
                        } elseif ($evaluacion == "tercer_ev") {
                            $instruccion2 .= " AND tercer_ev IS NOT NULL";
                        } else {
                            $instruccion2 .= " AND 1=0"; // No se seleccionará ningún registro si no se ha elegido una evaluación
                        }
                        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, $instruccion2) or die("Fallo en la consulta");

                        $nfilas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);
                        if ($nfilas > 0) {
                            print("<TABLE class='table'>\n");
                            print("<TR>\n");
                            print("<TH>MATERIA</TH>\n");
                            print("<TH>ID_ALUMNO</TH>\n");
                            print("<TH>ALUMNO</TH>\n");
                            print("<TH>CORREO</TH>\n");
                            print("<TH>NOTA</TH>\n");
                            print("<TH>INGRESAR</TH>\n");
                            print("</TR>\n");

                            while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)) {
                                print("<TR>\n");
                                print("<TD>" . $resultado['materia'] . "</TD>\n");
                                print("<TD>" . $resultado['id_alumno'] . "</TD>\n");
                                print("<TD>" . $resultado['alumno'] . "</TD>\n");
                                print("<TD>" . $resultado['correo'] . "</TD>\n");
                                if ($evaluacion == "primer_ev") {
                                    $nota = $resultado['primer_ev'];
                                    print("<TD>" . ($nota != 0 ? $nota : 'N/A') . "</TD>\n");
                                } elseif ($evaluacion == "segunda_ev") {
                                    $nota = $resultado['segunda_ev'];
                                    print("<TD>" . ($nota != 0 ? $nota : 'N/A') . "</TD>\n");
                                } elseif ($evaluacion == "tercer_ev") {
                                    $nota = $resultado['tercer_ev'];
                                    print("<TD>" . ($nota != 0 ? $nota : 'N/A') . "</TD>\n");
                                }
                                
                                echo "<div class='dashboard__item'>";
                                echo "<div class='card2' id='pitola' style='display: none;'>";
                                    echo "<div>";
                                    echo "<form action='calificaciones3.php?materia=%' method='post' onsubmit='return validar()'>";
                                    echo "  <h5>Nota para ".$resultado['alumno']." en ".$evaluacion."</h5>";
                                    echo "  <p>Nota: <input type='text' id='nota' name='nota'></p>";
                                    echo "  <span id='errorNota' style='color:red;display:none;'>Ingrese una nota válida</span>";
                                    echo "  <p>Actitud: <input type='text' id='actitud' name='actitud'></p>";
                                    echo "  <span id='errorActitud' style='color:red;display:none;'>Ingrese una actitud válida</span>";
                                    echo "  <p>Comentario: <input type='text' id='comentario' name='comentario'></p>";
                                    echo "  <span id='errorComentario' style='color:red;display:none;'>Ingrese un comentario válido</span>";
                                    echo "  <input type='submit' name='guardar' value='GUARDAR'>";
                                    echo "</form>";
                                    echo "  <input type='button' name='comprobar' value='CANCELAR' onclick='cerrar()'>";
                                    echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">GO BACK</a>";                                                                               
                                    echo "</div>";
                                echo " </div>";     
                                print("<TD><input type='submit' class='nota' n  ame='nota' value='Nota' onclick='abrir()'></TD>\n");
                                print("</TR>\n");
                ?>
```

y para rematar en el boton de tipo submit con el name guardar, es un query para modificar la nota en mi bbdd:

```
<?php
                                if (isset($_POST['guardar'])) {
                                    echo "<script language='javascript'>
                                    alert('hola') ;
                                    </script>"; 
                                    $nota = $_POST['nota'];
                                    $actitud = $_POST['actitud'];
                                    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
                        
                                    if ($evaluacion == 'primer_ev') {
                                        $query = "UPDATE calificaciones SET primer_ev = '$nota', comentario = '$comentario', actitud = '$actitud' WHERE id_alumno = " . $resultado['id_alumno'];
                                        
                                    } elseif ($evaluacion == 'segunda_ev') {
                                        $query = "UPDATE calificaciones SET segunda_ev = '$nota', comentario = '$comentario', actitud = '$actitud' WHERE id_alumno = " . $resultado['id_alumno'];
                                    } elseif ($evaluacion == 'tercer_ev') {
                                        $query = "UPDATE calificaciones SET tercer_ev = '$nota', comentario = '$comentario', actitud = '$actitud' WHERE id_alumno = " . $resultado['id_alumno'];
                                    }
                                    
                                    if (mysqli_query($conexion, $query)) {
                                        echo $query;
                                    } else {
                                        echo $query;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            print("</TABLE>\n");
                        } else {
                            print("Seleccione una evaluación.");
                        }
                    }
                        mysqli_close($conexion);
                    ?>
```

Pues bien, todo funciona (o eso creo) hasta que en el div con el formulario, agrego cualquier dato, como podéis comprobar en el último **if (isset($_POST['guardar']))**, hago echos, no salen por pantalla, ya he preguntado a varias personas y ninguno ha entendido la razón.

-Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si verificas el codigo fuente, es decir, el html retornado en tu navegador, no aparece por ningun lugar del codigo?

Comment: ¿ y el alert si se imprime?

Comment: Si, el html si se muestra, pero al enviar el form, los alerts de después de los echos que me muestran el form, ya no.

Comment: El problema principal que veo es que no estás escogiendo el mejor camino para resolver esto. Podrías simplemente tener un `select option` con cada materia, escuchar los cambios de ese select y traer los datos de la materia seleccionada usando Ajax. Eso te permitirá escribir un código más limpio, y actualizar el contenido de la página sin necesidad de recargarla, separando además responsabilidades.